# Force "Select the Associated Content" (Data Source) dialog

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is it possible to configure a placeholder/rendering to force the "Select the Associated Content" (ie Data Source) dialog to appear in the Page Editor, even when the current page has a template that is allowed by the rendering control?

**Update** To clarify, here are the steps to reproduce (I'm running 6.6):

1. Define a template `Repro` with a default layout that defines a `related-repros` placeholder
2. Define a rendering `Repro Rendering` that allows has a single Datasource Template of `Repro`
3. Define placeholder settings for `related-repros` that only allow `Repro Renderings`
4. Create two content items based on `Repro`: `Repro-1` and `Repro-2`
5. Edit `Repro-1` in Page Editor and add `Repro-2` to the `related-repros` placeholder as a `Repro Rendering`

The "Select the Associated Content" dialog doesn't appear, requiring `Repro-2` to be set after the fact by changing the data source. This is presumably because `Repro-1` (the current page) is a valid value for the datasource of `Repro Rendering`. What I want to do is force the dialog to appear anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it, but couldn't: If I use the Page Editor to add a component that requires a data source of the same template that was used to create the current item, I still get the *Associated Content* dialog.

However, if I leave the `Datasource Location` field on the rendering empty, I am able to reproduce it. But in that case the dialog *never* shows, not even if the current item is of a different template.

Can you confirm that you have configured a `Datasource Location` value on your rendering?

Can you also confirm that you are running the latest revision of 6.6 (rev 20130214)?

If this suggestion is not the solution, I will dive into it further, because I'm positive that this would be quite easy to fix since this entire process can be manipulated using pipeline processors.

Comment: Will confirm the relevance of `Datasource Location`. If it is indeed the problem, you can have the question and bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not quite clear but I assume you are talking about the page editor and Placeholder settings?

In that case, if you set the "Datasource Template" field of a sublayout with the preferred template and the "Data source" field of the sublayout is not prefilled, the "select associated content" dialog appears automatically.

Comment: Updated my question to be clearer. It looks like the dialog doesn't appear if the "Datasource Template" matches the current page.